# How to use a bash alias as a command line parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, alias

I looked this up on google but nobody has seemed to asked this before.  Is there a way I can set up an alias and use it as a command line argument to a program?

For example

```
ssh myserver
```

and `myserver` is defined to be the ip address of my server

Comment: shells use enviroment variables for such issues, i.e.`myServer=192.168.0.1`. and then are referenced like `ssh "$myServer"`. In general, don't waste your time with alias definitions, but learn to write `function`s that provide reusable services. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Good advice, except that you probably meant _shell_ variables rather than _environment_ variables.

Comment: @mklement0 : Yep, you're right about the semantics. Thanks for clarifying! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a way. But you will need to define two aliases.

First: Bash manual states (`LESS=+/'^ALIASES' man bash`)

> ALIASES
>   If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Also [documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) spec. [Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) for the link:

> If the value of the alias replacing the word ends in a <blank>, the shell shall check the next command word for alias substitution; this process shall continue until a word is found that is not a valid alias or an alias value does not end in a <blank>.

---

So, if you define these two aliases (Please keep the space at the end):

```
$ alias ssh='ssh '
$ alias myserver='192.168.0.1'
$ set -x
$ ssh myserver
+ ssh 192.168.0.1
```

Clear the aliases with:

```
$ unalias ssh
$ unalias myserver
```

**Note1**: also documented in `ksh` and `zsh` manuals

**Note2**: Tested as working correctly in `dash` (no documentation found).

[Wikipedia entry on "alias" chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29#Chaining)

Comment: [This behavior is specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01): _If the value of the alias replacing the word ends in a <blank>, the shell shall check the next command word for alias substitution; this process shall continue until a word is found that is not a valid alias or an alias value does not end in a <blank>._

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the comment and link.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no, your shell won't replace command line parameters for you.

In your *specific* example, you actually have several alternatives.  You could edit your `~/.ssh/config` file and add an entry like:

```
Host myserver
  HostName 1.2.3.4
```

And now when you run `ssh myserver`, ssh will actually connect to host `1.2.3.4`.

You can also maintain a `~/.hosts` file that looks like:

```
myserver 1.2.3.4
```

Now anything that uses the system resolver -- which includes `ssh` -- will translate `myserver` to `1.2.3.4`.

Answer (score 1):

[larsks' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243885/45375) contains a terse explanation and a helpful solution specific to `ssh` use; to complement it with a more generic explanation:

With the exception of the alias chaining described in [BinaryZebra's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244078/45375), **aliases generally can only be used as command *names*, not command *arguments***, at least not directly.

To **use non-literals (value placeholders) as command *arguments***, you have the following options (leaving aside other [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) such as globbing, brace expansion, or arithmetic expansion):

- Reference a **variable**; e.g.: `ssh "$myserver"`, previously defined as, e.g., `myserver=1.2.3.4`, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`.
- Use a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution); i.e., a command whose stdout output will serve as the argument value; e.g.: `ssh "$(echo '1.2.3.4')"`

However, you can also **use a shell *function* to provide a wrapper for a command with predefined arguments**; e.g.:

```
# Define the function, typically in ~/.bashrc
# "$@" safely passes all arguments through to `ssh`.
# (If the arguments must partly go *before* the predefined argument, more work is needed.)
sshmyserver() {
  ssh 1.2.3.4 "$@"
}

# Use the function, optionally with arguments.
sshmyserver
```